# Find $A_1,A_2, A_3, A_4$ such that $\lvert A_i \cap A_j\lvert = \lvert i-j \lvert$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

Give example of four sets $A_1,A_2, A_3, A_4$ such that $\lvert A_i \cap A_j\lvert = \lvert i-j \lvert$ for every two integers $i$ and $j$ with $1\leq i < j \leq 4$.

I was able to solve this problem with the following sets: $A_1 = \{1,4,5,8,9,10\}$, $A_2 = \{1,3,6,7\}$, $A_3 = \{2,3,4,5\}$ and $A_4 = \{2,6,7,8,9,10\}$. I used a naive method of saying "well, $A_1$ and $A_2$ need to have one element in common, so we'll put a 1 in both, and $A_3$ and $A_4$ need to have one element in common, so we'll put a 2 in both", etc. etc. However, this seems like a rather unsatisfying way of solving this problem.

The next problem in this book asks the reader to create 2 problems that are suggested by this exercise, and solve one of them. This is a problem, as I can't seem to figure out what this exercise is attempting to suggest, since I don't see any pattern going on. So my question is, is there some type of pattern I am missing that I can use to arrive at a more general solution to this problem? Thanks!

Comment: i think the discrete math tag is more appropriate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's anything unsatisfying about your solution. It's what I would do too.

One simple generalization would be to describe a general solution for a different number of sets than $4$ -- that is $A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_k$ with the same condition on $|A_i\cap A_j|$.

A more general generalization would be to generalize over the condition too: Suppose we're given $f:\{1,2,\ldots,k\}^2\to\mathbb N$, can we find sets $A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_n$ such that $|A_i\cap A_j|=f(i,j)$ when $1\le i<j\le k$?

Your "unsatisfying" strategy ought to solve both these problems too.